# controlling environment for subprocess command

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, environment

I am trying to start a script from a specific absolute path using

```
from subprocess import check_output
```

If I run:

```
# myscript.py
check_command=['pwd']
ret=check_output(check_command,shell=True)
print(ret)
path_set_command=['cd MYABSPATH']
ret=check_output(path_set_command,shell=True)
ret=check_output(check_command,shell=True)
print(ret)
```

it prints two times the folder where `myscript.py` is located.
Hence, I understand that the environment variables in the shell are recreated each call to `check_output`.

How to set the path of a command with check_ouput?
I have tried to have my command as

```
ret=check_output(['cd MYABSPATH; ./otherscript.py'] ,shell=True)
```

however, if I pass arguments to my `otherscript.py` (appending them as extra item to the list containing the command) they are not correctly forwarded.

So how do I run `otherscript.py` in `MYABSPATH` with `foo` `bar` arguments?

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` when you pass a list as the first argument.

Comment: you mean for security to avoid malicious string injection?only trusted user access the script

Comment: No, it just isn't necessary. Passing a list lets you `exec` the command directly without the overhead of the shell processing it. Using a list and `shell=True` requires the list elements to be rejoined into a single string, then re-parsed into separate words. If you want shell processing, just pass a string in the first place.

Comment: thanks a lot, maybe this was the cause of all my problems in first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use cwd:

```
foo = check_output("pwd", cwd="/MYABSPATH", shell=True)
```

Comment: it does work if I don't add shell=True, otherwise it returns with non-zero value

Comment: still, I think this is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the [os module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) to change directories before you start your script. Then you should be able to access your script

```
import os
from subprocess import check_output

os.chdir('MYABSPATH')
ret = check_output(path_set_command, shell=True)
print(ret)
```

Comment: great. I think this us going to work. do you know if there is a way to achieve this usig subprocess only

Comment: Why would you use subprocess only? It's a hacky way of writing bash code in python. Use the python modules which are available if you're going to write python code

Comment: If you need to do it only in subprocess, use cwd as check_output parameter

Comment: @Hannu's answer is a more direct answer to the question - if you want to use check_output then go with his answer

Comment: of course I could use os in python. but I think Hannus solution is cleaner